# Переход между Activity вылетает приложение

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-intent

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final Button ok = findViewById(R.id.ok);
    ok.setText("OK");

    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("second");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

}

вот мой код, никак не могу понять, почему при нажатии на кнопку оно сразу же выдает ошибку и закрывается?

Answer (score 2):

Потому что у вас что-то непонятное в интенте. Смотрите внимательнее примеры

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: при использовании "this" выдает ошибку
error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(<anonymous OnClickListener>,Class<second>)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to String)
constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context)

Comment: @lisa замените `this` на `MainActivity.this`